# Making a simple ASP webpage that displays updating values from C# program

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have never used ASP.NET before and I don't quite understand how the MVC system works, but my application is much more simple than the tutorials provided.

I have a webpage in HTML, and I currently have a C# program that gets key presses from my keyboard (Making a webpage that displays key presses). Both of these work, and the C# program prints to the terminal.

I can't however, seem to connect the two, by making a web page that has data bindings so that whenever a C# class updates, it changes the HTML content without page refresh.

This would probably require learning a lot, but I'm hoping to make it with a few files (maybe a controller isn't needed since the page has no interaction?). I'm not sure how to even make a DOTNET project, as the sample one has many built-in pages and routes that I don't understand.

So basically, this is my C# program (with DLL in the same dir)

```
using System;
using WootingAnalogSDKNET;
// We'll also include this for the Thread.Sleep call we'll have later on
using System.Threading;

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;



Console.WriteLine("Hello Analog SDK!");

// Initialise the SDK
var (noDevices, error) = WootingAnalogSDK.Initialise();
// If the number of devices is at least 0 it indicates the initialisation was successful
if (noDevices >= 0) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Analog SDK Successfully initialised with {noDevices} devices!");
}           
else {
    Console.WriteLine($"Analog SDK failed to initialise: {error}");
    System.Environment.Exit(1);
}


while (true) {
    var (keys, readErr) = WootingAnalogSDK.ReadFullBuffer(20);
    if (readErr == WootingAnalogResult.Ok)
    {
        // Go through all the keys that were read and output them
        foreach (var analog in keys)
        {
            Console.Write($"({analog.Item1},{analog.Item2})");
        }

        // We want to put on the new line character only if keys have been read and output to the console
        if (keys.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Read failed with {readErr}");
        // We want to put more of a delay in when we get an error as we don't want to spam the log with the errors
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    // We want to have a bit of a delay so we don't spam the console with new values
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: You need to use javascript in order to communicate from the client side of the website to the server side in the way you outlined.  You should also be using a c# project template meant for web, a simple console application will not do.  C# will not be able to check what key was pressed on the clients machine, because the c# is not running on their machine.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I was using a DOTNET template app with the SDK already loaded in which seemed to work. I put javascript into my HTML that would call @Model.xxx() in a loop, however as soon as the page is fully loaded, the Model seems to 'disappear' and I can't communicate with it.

This app is also only going to be locally hosted as OBS can overlay a local site as a stream overlay.

Comment: Yes, this is how the web works.  The server (c# side) sends the "rendered" page to the client, and then they interact with it locally in their browser.   All c# code will run on the server, js will run in their browser.  Regardless of it all being on one computer, there will always be this server/client relationship.

Comment: You might want to scrap the web idea and use something like winforms or wpf.  It seems like you have a good knowledge of c#, so that route will likely have you up and running much faster.

Comment: Thanks, will try that soon! I was hoping with the server/client relationship thing that using runat="server" would help but I don't have enough knowledge to get that working